# How to replace AVPlayerLayer for AVPictureInPictureController?

Tags: avplayer, avplayerlayer

I am working on PIP mode, as per the requirement in PIP mode I need to start another player as soon as current AVPlayer ends. Currently PIP mode closes automatically as it ends. Creating new AVPictureInPictureController object isn't starting in PIP mode.

BOOL isPiPActive = NO;

```
if ((nil != _mPictureInPictureController) {
 isPiPActive = _mPictureInPictureController.isPictureInPictureActive;
}

_mPictureInPictureController =  [[AVPictureInPictureController alloc] initWithPlayerLayer:aNewPlayerLayer];
if (isPiPActive) {
      NSLog(@"PIP Active by previous layer");
      [_mPictureInPictureController startPictureInPicture];

}
```

Can anyone suggest how we can play new AVPlayer to continue in PIP?

Comment: Any luck with this? or other methods of working around it?